# How can I connect to a REPL and send and read data?

Tags: shell, process, repl

Let us say I have a command to start a REPL. How do I most easily read output and send input? A minimal example with shell, sending ls and reading the output would be appreciated.

The shell should preferably not be opened in a buffer, but run in the background, if that isn't very hard.

Comment: Even though I mentioned ls and shell I would appreciate a general answer.

Comment: https://github.com/kaz-yos/eval-in-repl/

Comment: Note to self: see if https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Filter-Functions.html is what you want.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called `comint-mode` - the system which underlies most (all?) emacs interaction modes (lisp, scheme, shell, python, &c).

Here are some starting points:

- [Comint: Writing your own Command Interpreter](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/comint-writing-command-interpreter)
- [Comint Mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode)